# Simple dropdown menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new at javascript and I can't seem to get this simple dropdown menu to work. This is what I have done so far :

Html code:

```
    <ul>    
        <li onClick='showMenu()'>
            <a href="#" >Birds</a>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="">Ratites</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Fowl</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Neoaves</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

CSS code:

```
a {
    color: #06c;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: pink;
    float: left;
}

li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
 function showMenu(){
       document.getElementByClass("menu").style.display="block";
 }
```

My javascript code isn't working. Why won't my nested list show when I click?
Here is a jsfiddle link to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/wkmd7h0r/13/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClass`. Fixed code:

```
function showMenu() {
     document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

Also `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList collection, so you should use `[0]` to get the first element in this collection.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wkmd7h0r/14/

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wkmd7h0r/17/) of more advanced functionality with `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. Your advanced example helped me as well.:)

Comment: Can you please "translate" to me this piece of code `var className = subMenu.className.indexOf('active') !== -1 ? 'menu' : 'menu active';` I'm sensing it's a shorthand for if-then-else statement, but I can't seem to get the longhand version to work.

Comment: `subMenu.className.indexOf('active') !== -1` checks is current submenu className contains active substring (so it's `menu active`, then indexOf returns not -1, but index of "active" occurrence). In this case className is set to `menu`, and since submenu is no longer active it's hidden, because it's was for `active` class that showed a menu with display: block.